# Probability -$2$ on just one occasion.

Tags: probability

A die is thrown three times. Show the probability of scoring a $2$ on just one occasion in the probability tree diagram.

My attempt 
[image]

Please somebody check it. Is this correct? or are there any other alternatives?

Comment: this m,ethod is inefficient. $\binom{3}{1}\frac{1}{6}^{1}\cdot\frac{5}{6}^2$

Comment: But, I do need to draw the tree diagram as well

Comment: @ThomasAndrews fair enough

Comment: @NeWtoN your result is right, so i guess all is cool?

Comment: @Socrates,  however the answer given in my book is $\frac {1}{8}$

Comment: @NeWtoN You'd have to consult your tutor. I don't see how it could be $1/8$

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how you'd get 1/8. Is that the *exact* language of the question - did you copy it exactly as it is written?

Comment: @Thomas, yeah. That's same

Comment: By the way nice technique to solve question (+1) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram and answer is correct. If we cross check answer you obtained from tree diagram with the method suggested by Socrates we get the same answer.

Maybe answer in book is wrong or something missing in question in the book.